# Flutter pub get issue

Tags: flutter, package

[image][image]

When I want add `video_trimmer` package, show this issue

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  video_player: ^0.10.9+1
  video_trimmer: ^0.2.4
```